# How to convert DifferenceRoot into a special function?

Tags: differential-equations, complex, series-expansion

```
Clear["Global`*"];

f[z_] := z^(2 m) /(1+z)^m

res = SeriesCoefficient[f[z], {z, -1, -1}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[m, PositiveIntegers]]
```

The result is a `DifferenceRoot` form solution.

How to convert it into a special function:

(*  ((-4)^(-1 + m) m Pochhammer[3/2, -1 + m])/Pochhammer[3, -1 + m]  *)

or

(*  -(((-1)^m (2m)!)/((m-1)!(m+1)!))   *)

I tried

```
sol = RSolveValue[{(-\[FormalN] + 
         2 m) \[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (1 + \[FormalN]) \[FormalY][
        1 + \[FormalN]] == 0, \[FormalY][0] == 1} //. {\[FormalY] -> 
     y, \[FormalN] -> n}, y[n], n]
```

(*  -((2 m Pochhammer[1 - 2 m, -1 + n])/Pochhammer[2, -1 + n])  *)

This result is incorrect.

I know that `FunctionExpand` should be used, but there are two variables `m` and `n` in the equation. I don't know how to handle them.

Comment: ……你那代码里，混了中文括号。

Comment: @xzczd  Handwriting on mobile phones. Edited, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[z_] := z^(2 m)/(1 + z)^m

res = Assuming[Element[m, PositiveIntegers],
  SeriesCoefficient[f[z], {z, -1, -1}] // FullSimplify]

(* -((2 m Pochhammer[1 - 2 m, -2 + m])/Gamma[m]) *)
```

Under the given assumption this is equivalent to your desired result.

```
Assuming[Element[m, PositiveIntegers],
 res == ((-4)^(-1 + m) m Pochhammer[3/2, -1 + m])/Pochhammer[3, -1 + m] // 
  FullSimplify]

(* True *)
```